# Adjust column value based on difference between 2 dates

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have sales data at the start of every month in a quarter.

Example: For 22-Q1 quarter, I have sales on 3 dates (1st Jan, 1st Feb and 1st March)

| Date | Country | Region | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2022 | UK | EMEA | 100,000 |
| 02/01/2022 | UK | EMEA | 170,000 |
| 03/01/2022 | UK | EMEA | 120,000 |
| 01/01/2022 | US | AMS | 90,000 |
| 02/01/2022 | US | AMS | 110,000 |
| 03/01/2022 | US | AMS | 160,000 |

My requirement is to extrapolate the Sales data between the 2 given dates based on difference between the 2 dates and concatenate them to the same table.

For example for 2nd Jan, I calculate the date difference between 1st Jan and 1st Feb, which is 31 days and increment Sales amount by (1/31) and for 3rd Jan, I increment Sales amount by (2/31).. so on until 31st Jan.

After the month change, the date difference needs to be recalculated between 1st Feb and 1st March and similar increment on Sales needs to be applied

Comment: I've gone ahead and removed the tag spam here; please only tag the RDBMS you are *really* using. Tagging multiple conflicting technologies makes your question unclear and thus *harder* to answer. It is also unlikely to get your question "more views" and likely to have the opposite effect, where only users who know *all* the RDBMS you have (mis)tagged will entertain the question; that is often a very small portion of the user base. Tag spam is far more likely to result in your question receiving downvotes and/or being closed as unclear. Please [edit] your question to retag the correct RDBMS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a UDTF to generate the rows for each day of the month along with an extrapolation of the sales.

```
create or replace table T1 as 
select 
COLUMN1::date   as Date,
COLUMN2::string as Country,
COLUMN3::string as Region,
COLUMN4::number(38,2) as Sales
from (values
('01/01/2022','UK','EMEA',100000),
('02/01/2022','UK','EMEA',170000),
('03/01/2022','UK','EMEA',120000),
('01/01/2022','US','AMS',90000),
('02/01/2022','US','AMS',110000),
('03/01/2022','US','AMS',160000)
);

create or replace function EXTRAPOLATE_MONTH_TO_DAYS(MONTH_START date, VAL float)
returns table (DAY_DATE date, VAL float)
language javascript
as
$$
{
    initialize: function (argumentInfo, context) {
    },
    processRow: function (row, rowWriter, context) {
        const DAY = 86400000; // Milliseconds per day.
        let firstDay = row.MONTH_START;
        let lastDay = new Date(row.MONTH_START.getFullYear(), row.MONTH_START.getMonth() + 1, 0);
        let daysInMonth = lastDay.getDate();
        let valPerDay = row.VAL / daysInMonth;
        let sum = 0;
        let curDate = row.MONTH_START;
        for (let i = 1; i <= daysInMonth; i++) {
            sum += valPerDay;
            rowWriter.writeRow({DAY_DATE:new Date(firstDay.getTime()+DAY*(i-1)),VAL:sum});
        }
    },
}
$$;


select   DATE
        ,COUNTRY
        ,REGION
        ,SALES
        ,DAY_DATE
        ,round(VAL,2)::number(38,2) EXTRAPOLATED_RUNNING_TOTAL
from T1, table(EXTRAPOLATE_MONTH_TO_DAYS(DATE, SALES::float) over (partition by COUNTRY, REGION order by DATE))
;
```

First five rows:

| DATE | COUNTRY | REGION | SALES | DAY_DATE | EXTRAPOLATED_RUNNING_TOTAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | US | AMS | 90000 | 2022-01-01 | 2903.23 |
| 2022-01-01 | US | AMS | 90000 | 2022-01-02 | 5806.45 |
| 2022-01-01 | US | AMS | 90000 | 2022-01-03 | 8709.68 |
| 2022-01-01 | US | AMS | 90000 | 2022-01-04 | 11612.90 |
| 2022-01-01 | US | AMS | 90000 | 2022-01-05 | 14516.13 |